# Will this code read mouse button X on many button mouses?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently don't have a many mouse button mouse at home, but i found nothing about this online.

Will `Input.GetMouseButton(x)` will read my mouse Xth button for example.

Will this return true if i hold down my mouse 4th mouse button?

`bool holding = Input.GetMouseButton(4);`

The unity doc only mentions mouse button 1,2 and 3 :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, yes the function `Input.GetMouseButton(4)` will read in the 4th mouse button on your mouse when held down :)

(I tested this like half a year ago, Unity doc team should have mentioned this indeed that it can read any mouse buttons, so we dont need to test it :P)

Comment: Yeah as i thought, but i needed a verification!